# Click on buttons on the page that has got the same class using capybara with siteprism

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

There are 20 different buttons to expect and needs to be clicked through to expect and verify the urls inside the code. I have tried different ways to implement my tests but they are failing.

I'm trying something like:

```
 page.all(:class => 'action red').each do |button|
   c = button.find(:class => 'action view red')
   c.click   
   page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(@new_window)
   expect('some element on those 20 different browsers sessions before closing them') 
   page.driver.browser.close
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error:

> ArgumentError: invalid keys :class, should be one of :count, :minimum,
>   :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait

Any can help me in the code how to perform get the elements of all the 20 buttons, store them and click them to expect the url each of them before closing it

Comment: Thats a sample code:     <div class="buttons">
<a class="action red" href="#">  </a>
</div>

Comment: Does clicking on each of the buttons - open a new window, or does it change the current page?  Also, what version of Capybara are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your "buttons" aren't buttons - since they are `<a>` elements they are actually links, styled to look like buttons.

Assuming that clicking each of these links actually opens a new window (since you're attempting to switch to a new window) then the code would be something like

```
page.all(:link, class: ['action', 'red']).each do |link|
  win = page.window_opened_by { link.click }
  page.within_window(win) do
    expect(page).to ... # whatever you need to expect
  end
  win.close()
end
```

Note this doesn't use any driver specific (.driver.browser...) methods - you should stay away from them whenever possible since they are generally a sign you're doing something wrong.  Additionally, the `:class` option wasn't universally available on all of Capybaras builtin selector types until v2.10, so you will need to be using a newer version of Capybara for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting another error:       ArgumentError: invalid keys :class, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait, :href

Comment: This is what I'm doing:                                                             
  page.all(:link, class: ['action', 'red']).each do |link|
      link.click
      expect(page).to have_css
  end

Comment: @Ayub check the version of Capybara you’re using